Single Machine Job Scheduling With Release Dates and No Idling Constraint
I'm trying to model a linear job scheduling optimisation problem. There is a single machine and N jobs $J_1, J_2, ..., J_N$. Each job consists of one step with processing time $p_1, p_2, ..., p_N$. Each job also has a release date $r_1, ..., r_N$. I want to minimise the average completion time (defined as $startTime_i + p_i - r_i$). I have the normal constraints, such as $startTime_i > 0$, ordering constraints ($x_{ij} + x_{ji} = 1$ where $x_{ij}$ means task order), and I have $S_j >= S_i + p_i - M (1 - x_{ij})$ for the starting times. However, I want to add a constraint so that the machine cannot be idle. If a job finishes and there is one job, I want the machine to pick that job even if it would be shorter to wait until a short job arrives. How could I add that constraint?

Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11996/single-machine-job-scheduling-with-release-dates-and-no-idling-constraint

Change the $S_j\ge S_i+p_i−M(1−x_{ij})$ constraint into $S_j = S_i+p_iz_{2ij}$ and introduce the following constraints:
$$z_{1ij}+z_{2ij}+z_{3ij}=1$$
$$-Mz_{1ij} + 0z_{2ij} + 1z_{3ij}\le\left(\sum_kx_{ik}-x_{jk}\right) - 1\le-1z_{1ij}+0z_{2ij}+Mz_{3ij}$$
where $M$ is a large, constant number in $\mathbb{R}^+$, $z_{1ij}$ is a binary decision variable denoting if $\left(\sum\limits_kx_{ik}-x_{jk}\right) - 1$ is in the range $[-M,-1]$, $z_{2ij}$ is a binary decision variable denoting if $\left(\sum\limits_kx_{ik}-x_{jk}\right) - 1=0$, and $z_{3ij}$ is a binary decision variable denoting if $\left(\sum\limits_kx_{ik}-x_{jk}\right) - 1$ is in the range $[1,M]$.
It's important to understand that if $\left(\sum\limits_kx_{ik}-x_{jk}\right) - 1=0$, then job $j$ follows job $i$
